# Exclude one category in a custom post type

Tags: php, post, categories

I have a custom post type called 'portcat' and I want to exclude one portcat category ('weather' - which has an ID of '5') from the page. What can I add to the below code to exclude it?

```
<?php
   $temp = $wp_query;
   $wp_query = null;
   $wp_query = new WP_Query();
                 $args = array(
                 'post_type' => 'port',
                 'paged' => $paged,
                 'posts_per_page' => get_theme_option("portfolio_work_count"),           
                 );


   if (isset($_GET['slug'])) {
     $args['tax_query']=array(
                         array(  
                          'taxonomy' => 'portcat',
                          'field' => 'slug',
                          'terms' => $_GET['slug'] 
                        ) 
                    );
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[from wordpress codex :](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Exclude Posts Belonging to Category

Display all posts from post-type except those from a custom term :

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
      'post_type'   => 'port',  // only query post type
      'tax_query'   => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'portcat',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => '$_GET['slug']',
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN') // seems that's what you're missing
            ),
       )
    );
```

Comment: you got 2 answers at the same time ;)

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these worked. It could be because these are custom 'Portfolio' Posts...not normal 'Blog' Posts. Is there another way as I personally can't find a solution?

Comment: Ah yes indeed, sorry did not see it was for custom taxonomy. So modified my answer.

Comment: I don't see a reference to the 'weather' (ID=5) category there so I assume I need to add that in order to exclude it? Would it be: 'operator'  => 'NOT IN(ID=5)' ?

Comment: Yes in the array tax_query you see a coma at the of the first array. You can as many parameters as you want. This example will exlude the term you sent through GET paramter and show all others. This is detailed on the codex (search for "tax_query" on this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query